VS Code 1.86.2 does not open in Mac OS sequoia
I need this version because our remote development setup (I ssh into a linux machine using a proxy jump) for some reason doesn't work with later versions it gets stuck in "Downloading VSCode Server".
So, after upgrading MacOs to the latest version Sequoia VS Code no longer works. It just does nothing. I have tried removing all of the configuration files using AppCleaner and redownload it but nothing happens.
When i click on it, it does nothing. I just get an apple screen asking me to report the issue.
Any help getting vscode or the remote environment working will be greatly appreciated.

I would consult the vscode github

Wanting something released in Jan 2024 to support the recently available macOS isn't realistic. Apple deliberately broke quite a lot of APIs, so practically you have to use latest VS Code release.

Known issue:  See their github for resolution.  A lot of people have solved by reinstalling VS code and/or updating to the latest:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/229463
